# Tensorflow: Attention heatmap visualization

Tags: python, tensorflow, attention-model

I am trying to create a heat map the same as the image below using attention in `TensorFlow r1.4`.

[image: attention_heatmap]

I am using [tf.contrib.seq2seq.BahdanauAttention](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/BahdanauAttention) and [tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/AttentionWrapper) for implementation of attention mechanism. I have seen a workaround here ([Visualizing attention activation in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601552/visualizing-attention-activation-in-tensorflow)) but I think it will not work with my current setup as that workaround uses old version of `TensorFlow`.

**EDIT**

I might be close to finding the solution by debugging the model with [tfdbg](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger) but I don't know what Tensors should I look for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't know if you ever refered this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40601552/visualizing-attention-activation-in-tensorflow